# Vertically align div within div, and

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div, and then inside the div put the date on the left, and two icons on the right. Both should be vertically centered, have some margin to the edge, and margin between other elements in the parent div. But right now when I run it, the icons end up in strange positions, often clipping out of the div.

```css
.c-project-bar {
  width: 355px;
  height: 30px;
  display: table;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.c-project-date {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #828282;
  font-size: 14px
}

.c-project-github-icon {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-project-bar">
  <p class="c-project-date">Aug, 2017</p>
  <span class="c-project-github-icon"></span>
  <span class="c-project-github-icon"></span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/enyzhxyz/

Edit:

Everyone's answers are awesome, it seemed a major issue was the fact that the

was inheriting { margin: 0px; }, and it was throwing a wrench in everyone's solutions. I solved this by including a margin: initial, before using any margin style later, so it first removed { margin: 0px; } then added the one I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give `float: right` you cannot vertically centre. Instead, use the inline-block technique:

```css
.c-project-bar {
  width: 355px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background: #ccf;
}
.c-project-date, .c-project-icons {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.c-project-icons {
  text-align: right;
}
.c-project-github-icon {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 25px;
  width:25px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-project-bar">
  <p class="c-project-date">Aug, 2017</p>
  <div class="c-project-icons">
    <span class="c-project-github-icon"></span>
    <span class="c-project-github-icon"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would have suggested you the `transform` and `position` centering technique, but it would be a too much of overkill for this solution. I have given some background colour to see it is perfectly vertical align middle. Although it uses slightly extra markup, this would be the right way that works on browsers that don't support `flexbox` too.

Comment: In general do you think transform/position should be the method I use when trying to get this effect?

Comment: Also this solution's vertical centering fix only seems to work if you remove the height from c-project-bar, which is something I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Actually I take back what I said in my last comment. Maybe it is some inherited style causing the issue for me, because I'm trying other solutions that run fine when I use jsfiddle or run the snippet, but then have strange results on my site.

Comment: @OliverHare Please never ever use `height`. Height should be automatically calculated from the contents. `:)`

Comment: @OliverHare Did this work out for you then? If you wanna provide the full code, I can help you further as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using css `flexbox`.

```css
body {
background-color: #696969;
}
.c-project-bar {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 355px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.c-project-date {
  color: #828282;
  font-size: 14px
}

.c-project-github-icon {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 25px;
  width:25px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-project-bar">
      <p class="c-project-date">Aug, 2017</p>
      <div> 
            <span class="c-project-github-icon"></span>
            <span class="c-project-github-icon"></span>
      </div>
     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this could be to use `transform`.

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

```css
.c-project-bar {
  width: 355px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.c-project-date {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  float: left;
  color: #828282;
  font-size: 14px
}

.c-project-github-icon {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 25px;
  width:25px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="c-project-bar">
      <p class="c-project-date">Aug, 2017</p>
      <span class="c-project-github-icon"></span>
      <span class="c-project-github-icon"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with `display: flexbox`.

```
.c-project-bar {
  display: flex; // power
  align-items: center; // aligning
  width: 355px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.c-project-date {
  margin-right: auto; // let's push other stuff to right side
  color: #828282;
  font-size: 14px
}

.c-project-github-icon {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 25px;
  width:25px;
}
```

[Fixed jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oboshto/enyzhxyz/3/)

Comment: This is working great, except I'm inheriting { margin: 0px; } in c-project-date, which is causing weird issues. How can I solve this?

Comment: nevermind, I solved it by setting the margin to initial, then on the next line setting my right-margin